# Negate numeric value in reg expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have response below in my script and I need to capture just 4 from below value and pass to next request

```
4,7,6,115,116.
```

here `115` and `116` are dynamic values. But I'm getting `116` directly from the response as dynamic value.

I tried with `(.^?),7,6` but there are plenty of values with the same boundaries. 
So, I want to negate `115` from the line to capture `4`.

```
(.^?),7,6,{Dontknow},${temp}
```

Can you please let me know the function to NEGATE `115` in the expression.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean, to be honest. Did you mean `(^.?)` by any chance? (The anchor at the beginning of the string, where it belongs)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by "negate" you mean "should not be", so try this:

```
^(.*?),7,6,(?!115).*?,${temp}
```

I put in a negative look-ahead that requires the 4th tern to *not* be `115`.

Also fixed the non-sensical `(.^?)`